# Where to remove Python 3.6 from PATH variable in macOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, path, homebrew, macos-catalina

I have installed Python 3.6.8 in macOS 10.15.4 Catalina using the installer obtained from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Later I have installed Python 3.7.7 via Homebrew and would now like to keep the  Python 3.6.0 but remove it from the `$PATH` environment variable. However, I am not able to find out where the `$PATH` variable is modified to include `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`, which is the first path in the `$PATH` variable.

Following are the paths where I looked into, but the file either does not exist or exists but doesn't contain the Python 3.6 bin path.

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_login
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.cshrc
- ~/.profile
- ~/.tcshrc
- ~/.zprofile
- /etc/paths
- /etc/paths.d
- /etc/profile
- ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

The `echo $PATH` command gives me:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Any ideas where can I modify the `$PATH` variable to remove `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` from it?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` neither exists. I have modified the question to include it,

Comment: Do you have something interesting under `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`?

Comment: Other than that, the vanilla PKG installer from www.python.org/downloads [echoes the `PATH` modification into the config file of your shell](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f4b229df7812f1788287095eb6b138bb21876a4/Mac/BuildScript/scripts/postflight.patch-profile#L48) and the choice is pretty limited, so the first question is how did you install Python and the second is whether you fiddled with the env manually.

Comment: Maybe a `grep -Iinr "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6" ~` will print something interesting.

Comment: Nothing related to Python in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`. As I wrote, I've installed Python using [this installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-368/) from Python.org. I haven't modified the `$PATH` var manually. Where is the config file for my shell located?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` will output the shell you're using right now. Did you try grepping the home dir?

Comment: Grepping home dir haven't found anything. My shell is `/bin/zsh
`.

Comment: Then it's the `~/.zprofile` file ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Mac/BuildScript/scripts/postflight.patch-profile#L80)). The PKG installer doesn't do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, must have overlooked it. The correct answer is that the `$PATH` variable is modified to include `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` in the `~/.zprofile` config file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you dont have it configured on your `/etc/profile`. Also,  there's a tool called `/usr/libexec/path_helper` which basically helps the system load every PATH configuration stored in `/etc/paths.d`. You can read more about it [here](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/05/where-paths-come-from/) Maybe that will be of help.

Comment: I've added `/etc/profile` to the list of paths where I couldn't find the Python 3.6 bin path.. Regarding `/etc/paths.d`, it's already mentioned  in the list.